# Define timerange in Matlab simply based on time (not date)

Tags: matlab, timetable

I am trying to use the Matlab timerange function to select rows of a timetable within a specific time interval, e.g. between 12:00:00 and 16:00:00. Because I have 30 different days, each day covering various timings, I would like to ignore the date and retrieve all the rows whose times fall within my time interval, irrespective of the day. If I only write the time in the line below, Matlab uses today by default. I would be very grateful if someone could help me finding out how to only use time (and not dates) as an index.

```
S = timerange('??? 12:00:00','??? 16:00:00');
Output = TT(S,:);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to @aksadv's answer, there's a slightly neater solution using `duration` types, like so:

```
times = datetime(2017, 01, randi([1 31], 10, 1), ...
    randi(24, 10, 1), randi(60, 10, 1), randi(60, 10, 1));
tt = timetable(times, rand(10, 1));
% Use TIMEOFDAY to convert datetimes into durations representing
% the time of day:
tt.times = timeofday(tt.times)
% TIMERANGE can be used with durations too. Use HOURS to construct
% the duration objects
tt(timerange(hours(12), hours(16)), :)
```

This uses [`timeofday`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeofday.html) to extract the time component, and [`hours`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hours.html) to create `duration` instances.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way that selects the rows after explicitly removing everything except the time information. Let `TT` be the input timetable.

```
% Create another timetable with the same time information
%  It also has one data column which represents the row index
tempTT = timetable(TT.Time, (1:height(TT))');

% remove the Year, Month, and Date information
tempTT.Time.Year  = 1;
tempTT.Time.Month = 1;
tempTT.Time.Day   = 1;

% Select the desired timerange
S = timerange('1-1-1 12:00:00','1-1-1 16:00:00');

% Get the row indices of the selected rows
idxSel = tempTT(S,:).Variables;

% Select the desired rows from the original timetable
Output = TT(idxSel,:);
```